XmlSerialization. When I get rid of the prefix, I get empty xmlns
My task requires sending special xml files through a C# program. Examples of xml files were provided to me. To avoid hardcoding, I decided to create a hierarchy of classes that I can serialize and get the required xml files.
And here I encountered a problem.
(to avoid violating NDA I will give a fictitious xml example)
This is the kind of target xml file I should get:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<myObject xmlns="example_namespace">
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <details
        xmlns:tns="randomNamespace"
        xmlns="randomNamespace">
        <address>123 Main St</address>
    </details>
</myObject>

Here are the classes I've written:
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "example_namespace", ElementName = "myObject", IsNullable = true)]
    public class MyObject
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("details", Namespace = "randomNamespace")]
        public Details Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        [XmlElement("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tns", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Tns { get; set; } = "randomNamespace";
    }

When I serialize something like this, I get this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<myObject xmlns="example_namespace">
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <details
        xmlns:tns="randomNamespace"
        xmlns="randomNamespace">
        <tns:address>123 Main St</tns:address>
    </details>
</myObject>

As you can see, I get the "tns" prefix, that I don't need.
For the "Address" element, I tried to add "Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified":
        [XmlElement("address", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

But then I get an empty xmlns - xmlns="", that I don't need either:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<myObject xmlns="example_namespace">
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <details
        xmlns:tns="randomNamespace"
        xmlns="randomNamespace">
        <address xmlns="">123 Main St</address>
    </details>
</myObject>

Here's the way I serialize for debugging purposes:
            var myObject = new MyObject
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                Details = new Details { Address = "123 Main St" }
            };
    
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, myObject);
                Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            }

Honestly, I've tried a lot of things and my head is a mess, but I either get empty xmlns or I get the "tns" prefix. And I need to get rid of both.
So far the only option I have is to serialize to a string, then get rid of the unfortunate xmlns="" using the Replace method, but that's very ugly.
I've read that, for example, you can override the serializer itself, but I haven't figured out how that would help me, and besides, such an option would affect all classes when serializing, wouldn't it?
Could you please give me a hint?

The tns namespace is not used in the above xml, any xml parser will skip it, so no additional actions should be taken to enable it.

@AlexanderPetrov, do you mean I don't need to use "Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified"

Did you think about using data contract instead?
